# How to add difficulty levels to my number guessing game

Tags: python

hi so i have made a number guessing game and am wondering if there was any way to add difficulty levels to this game like they cud input "easy", "medium", "difficult" and then it wud change the numbers to guess from ie easy wud make it from 1-10, medium would be 1-50 and difficult wud be like 1-99 if u get my gist.

any help wud be much appreciated!

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

import random


_TIME_OUT = [False, False]

_TIME_LIMIT = 20

class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, time_out, player):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.time_out = time_out
        self.player = player

    def run(self):
        sleep(self.time_out)
        _TIME_OUT[self.player - 1] = True
        print('\a', end="") 

def main():
    _TIME_OUT[0] = False
    _TIME_OUT[1] = False

    tread_1 = MyThread(_TIME_LIMIT, 1)

    n = random.randint(1, 99)
    chances = 5

    
    tread_1.start()
    print(f"You have {_TIME_LIMIT} sec")

    guess = int(input("Player 1 please enter an integer from 1 to 99, you have 5 chances: " ))
    while n != "guess" and not _TIME_OUT[0]:
        chances -=1
        if chances == 0:
            print("out of chances, it is now player 2's turn to play. The number was", n)
            break
        if guess < n:
            print("guess is low you have",chances,"chances left")
            guess = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 99: "))
        elif guess > n:
            print ("guess is high you have",chances, "chances left")
            guess = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 99: "))
        else:
            print("you guessed it and have", chances, "chances left")
            break
            
    if _TIME_OUT[0]:
        print("Sorry, out of time!")

    tread_2 = MyThread(_TIME_LIMIT, 2)

    n1 = random.randint(1, 99)
    chances1 = 5

    tread_2.start()
    print(f"You have {_TIME_LIMIT} sec")

    guess1 = int(input("Player 2 please enter an integer from 1 to 99, you have 5 chances: "))
    while n1 != "guess" and not _TIME_OUT[1]:
        chances1 -=1
        if chances1 ==0:
            print("out of chances, the number was", n1)
            break
        if guess1 < n1:
            print("guess is low you have",chances1,"chances left")
            guess1 = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 99: "))
        elif guess > n1:
            print ("guess is high you have",chances1, "chances left")
            guess1 = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 99: "))
        else:
            print("you guessed it and have", chances1, "chances left")
            break

    if _TIME_OUT[1]:
        print("Sorry, out of time!")

    retry=input("would you like to play again? (please choose either 'yes' or 'no' )")
    while retry == "yes":
        print("mylist:[2, 3, '', 5, 6]")
        guess = int(input("Please enter the missing number in mylist: "))
        if guess != 4:
            print("Please try again")
            continue
        else:
            print("Good job, u can have more chances ")      
            main()
    if retry == "no":
        print("Okay. have a nice day! :D ")
    else:
        print("Invalid input")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this at the start of main() will work.

```
difficulty = input("Would you like it Easy, Medium or Difficult?")
if difficulty[0].upper() == "E":
    n = random.randint(1, 10)
elif difficulty[0].upper() == "M":
    n = random.randint(1, 50)
elif difficulty[0].upper() == "D":
    n = random.randint(1, 99)
else:
    raise Exception("You didn't type a difficulty.")
```

Comment: hi ive tried that but once i do that it tells me that n has been referenced before assignment. is thr any way to solve that?

Comment: You could solve it by using an Exception, I've added it above.